# Retrieving data from FireBase Realtime Database and using it

Tags: kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I want to retrieve data from my firebase database, then use that data (which is a Int) in a sum, and then update the database with the answer.

This is what I have so far
This is also in a separate class

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Texas")
            database.child("Texas").get().addOnSuccessListener {
                if (it.exists()){
                    var number = it.child("Number").value
                    if (number == Int || number == Long){
                        number += 1
                    }

                }else{
                    Log.e(TAG, "Invalid type transition $geofenceTransition")
                }
            }.addOnFailureListener {
                Log.e(TAG, "Invalid type transition $geofenceTransition")
            }
```

At the += sign I get a receiver type mismatch

Please help

Comment: can you share you JSON structure, or attach a screenshot of firebase database

Comment: Can you try this: `var number = it.child("Number").getValue(Long::class.java)`

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `number is Int || number is Long`?

Comment: I added the picture sorry for taking long

Comment: Thank you Van-Duyet Le it looks like it worked